# GNU parallel: execute one command parallel for all files in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-parallel

I am trying to parallelize particle simulations with different parameters to save some time. Therefore I wanted to use `GNUparallel` to run a bash script for the different parameters. The script reads a file and then performs the simulation eg :

`$bash script <<< input file`

However:-

`$cd ~/parameter_files ls | parallel bash script <<< {}`

does not work at all. I am a total newbie to Linux and GNUparallel, so hopefully someone can  help.

Comment: Please update the question with whether you have spent an hour walking through `man parallel_tutorial`

Comment: Please show your bash script and tell us its name.

Answer (score 5):

You're almost right, use double quotes around the command

```
ls | parallel "bash script <<< {}"
```

Otherwise the here string `<<<` would feed the input into the `parallel` command rather than each individual `bash script` commands

---

I find this use case to be quite unusual however, since it means that basically your script is reading the filename **string**. If you just want to pass the files as **arguments** to the script, you can use

```
ls | parallel bash script
```

or if you want to pass the **content** of the files using standard input

```
ls | parallel "bash script < {}"
```

Comment: The point is that Im reading the filename and then pass it as an argument to a python code. On the other hand I also need specific lines of the file besides its name to name my output variables.

Comment: @Physicus I see, so I assume that your python code instead of bash would do the file I/O stuff based on the given filename

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parallel` like this on each file of `~/parameter_files` directory:

```
find ~/parameter_files -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | parallel -0 bash ../script
```

- `find` command finds all the files inside `~/parameter_files` directory and returns them NUL terminated
- `parallel -0 bash ...` feeds each filename to your shell script and executes it.